# Unit tests aren't run with multiple build configurations in TFS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, msbuild

I am using MSBuild in my TFS Buildprocess using the DefaultTemplate to build multiple configurations(Debug/Release) of the same solution. When I build only release or only debug the unit tests are run but when I run the build with both configurations the unit tests are not run.

When I am running multiple configurations I have each of them Defined in the build definition under Process-> Items to Build-> Configurations to Build which is Mixed Platforms|Release,Mixed Platforms|Debug. When I run a single configuration I am using Mixed Platforms|Release or Mixed Platforms|Debug.

I am unable to put the entire log here(It is over 6000 lines long) but it appears that it isnt finding any of the testAssemblies.

**Edit:**

Here are the actual sections of the log. I'm not sure where Mixed Platforms\Release is coming from in the searchpathroot.

I should also add that we compile into our Source's folder because a few of our scripts only work in that layout.

**Debug Only(works)**

Run MSTest for Test Assemblies
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Product\Local.testsettings" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Debug\UnitTestCommon.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Release\UnitTestCommon.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestWCF\bin\Debug\UnitTestWCF.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestWCF\bin\Release\UnitTestWCF.dll" /publish:"http://dctfs2010.company.dc:8080/tfs/Product" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/964" /teamproject:"ProductName" /platform:"Mixed Platforms" /flavor:"Debug" 
Loading C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Product\Local.testsettings...
Loading C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Debug\UnitTestCommon.dll...
Loading C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Release\UnitTestCommon.dll...

**Debug and Release(Does not work)**

Run MSTest for Test Assemblies
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Product\Local.testsettings" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Mixed Platforms\Release" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Debug\UnitTestCommon.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestCommon\bin\Release\UnitTestCommon.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestWCF\bin\Debug\UnitTestWCF.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Test\UnitTestWCF\bin\Release\UnitTestWCF.dll" /publish:"http://dctfs2010.company.dc:8080/tfs/Product" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/962" /teamproject:"ProductName" /platform:"Mixed Platforms" /flavor:"Release" 
Directory "C:\Builds\6\ProductName\BuildName\Sources\Mixed Platforms\Release" not found.

Comment: They're not run at all? Why not? What does the build log say?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "run the build" and how exactly you are specifying multiple configurations?  Is it IDE or command line, solutions or projects...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my outputDirectory was setup wrong for how our projects are compiled. Which is where the searchpathroot problem came from.

Comment: Do you mean the "Test Assembly Filespec" which is usually `**\*test*.dll`? What exactly did you change? For an *accepted answer* it is not that helpflul.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the properties of your solution (the solution that you build as part of your build). You will have configuration manager. At the configuration manager you will be able to see 'Debug', 'Released', 'Mixed', etc any other configurations you may have defined. Can you see the test project checked to be build in the mixed configuration? If this is not being build, the test.dll will not be available which means, MSBuild will not have any tests to run.

Another way to verify why the tests are not running, is to look at the build drop directory and see if you can see the test.dll there. If the test.dll is not there then the problem is with how you have the projects configured in the configuration manager.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out :D